# querying result of a function which inserts data and returns set of ids

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a plpgsql function that returns table with and id column which represents all inserted data inside function. something like this:

```sql
create or replace function se_initial_games("tournamentId_" bigint)
returns table(
  "gameId" bigint
) as $$
declare
  n_teams bigint;
begin
  return query
  insert into single_elimination_tournaments_games (team_one_id, team_two_id, tournament_id)
  (select ...) returning id;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

It is returning results when running

```sql
select "gameId" from se_initial_games(1);
```

but not if I use it in a subquery e.g:

```sql
select g.* from games g where g.id in (select "gameId" as id from se_initial_games(1));
```

Something tells me function results after games table is read.

The problem is that the results of query `select g.* from games g g.id` don't include newly inserted ids from `in` subquery.

I ended up writing 2 queries for this.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you're trying to achieve? Add some data sample and the exact result you expect from your query.

Comment: Your example elides the important part, where "id" is coming from.  The simple explanation would be that the "id" returned by the function does not exist in table "games".

Comment: Your function does an `INSERT`, so you typically cannot repeat the test `se_initial_games(1)` as the second call will run into `UNIQUE` violations and error out. Speculating where we don't get the full picture here ...